# Is China still in control of the Galwan Valley in Ladakh?

Tags: china, india, territorial-dispute

In the beginning, I read that [China encroached 60sqkm land inside India](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2020/06/12/china-annexes-60-square-km-india-ladakh-simmering-tensions-erupt/#:%7E:text=between%20two%20superpowers-,China%20annexes%2060%20square%20km%20of%20India%20in%20Ladakh,tensions%20erupt%20between%20two%20superpowers&text=China%20has%20occupied%20more%20than,between%20the%20two%20Asian%20superpowers.) near the border. Then they [killed 20 Indian soldiers](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-53061476). Then Indian PM declared that [China never occupied any land](https://theprint.in/politics/no-one-entered-indian-territory-no-border-posts-were-occupied-pm-at-all-party-meet-on-china/445241/). Now, I see that Indian media reporting [Chinese have left their positions](https://www.ndtv.com/india-news/mutual-withdrawal-of-indian-chinese-troops-has-taken-place-most-likely-limited-to-galwan-sources-2257763).

I am a bit confused.

So, What is the latest situation in Ladakh regarding the Chinese occupation of Indian land?

Is China still in control of the Galwan Valley in Ladakh?

Answer (score 1):

This is an ongoing and evolving situation but it does appear to be the case that Chinese forces have left the valley. As stated in the question, Indian media is reporting that Chinese forces have retreated and this is apparently supported with [satellite photos](https://indianexpress.com/article/india/after-galwan-valley-troops-on-both-sides-start-pulling-back-in-hot-springs-sector-6494992/). [Eurasia Times](https://eurasiantimes.com/chinese-pla-troops-withdraw-from-galwan-valley-this-is-how-china-responds-to-indian-claims/) says that "Chinese state media – the Global Times acknowledged that India and China had agreed to withdraw troops from after Chinese Foreign Minister Wang Yi and Indian National Security Advisor Ajit Doval spoke on Sunday night."